# android viewpagerindicator tabpageIndicator tabs are not showing on/off

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator library, i used the TabPagerIndicator, the problem is although i can navigate from one page to another and see the titles corresponding to each page correctly, but i cannt see which tab is active and which is not.
in the screenshots available with the library code i can see a blue line drawn under the title of the selected tab, but in my app i cannt see that line at all.
i tried going through the code changing some resources but got nothing.
any help will be appreciated.
thx in advance

edit:
my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.apple.gallerapplication.GalleryActivity"
   >
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        />

        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/indicator"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity code

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        //viewpager
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));


        TabPageIndicator mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


    }
}
```

the pager adapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(customPagerEnum.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
    collection.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return CustomPagerEnum.values().length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
    return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());

}



@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: post your xml...and code

Comment: thx for replying, i have added my code

Comment: why not using the native `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` ?

Comment: thank you that solved my problem

Comment: i have posted it as an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Xml:

```
 <!-- use tablayout to display tabs  -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/your_color" />
```

in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorAccent</item>    //indicator color
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>                //indicator height
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/color_white</item>
</style>
```

here you can customize the `tabIndicator` properties